# How to setup standalone wiremock server under an application path

Tags: amazon-web-services, dockerfile, wiremock

I am trying to setup wiremock under an application path.

I have wiremock dockerized and running under some path `https://local.wiremock/` and that works fine, so I can access the admin like this `https://local.wiremock/__admin/docs`

However when I deploy to aws it needs to be under a path like this:
`https://aws-server.wiremock/simulator/__admin/docs`

And the addition of the application path `/simulator` breaks everything.

So I want to set it up locally so that it runs under:
`https://local.wiremock/simulator/__admin/docs`

I have been going through documentation and there's nothing there for standalone server configuration.
There is a `mappedUnder` xml field that could be useful but it cannot be set via docker.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by adding a [Request Wrapper](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/). The idea behind the Request Wrapper is that it intercepts the request and allows you to modify it before sending the request on. I think your solution would look something like...

```
public static class removeSimulatorPath extends StubRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public RequestFilterAction filter(Request request) {
        Request wrappedRequest = RequestWrapper.create()
                // lambda to replace the current URL with one without `/simulator`
                .transformAbsoluteUrl(url -> url.replace("/simulator", "")
                .wrap(request);

        return RequestFilterAction.continueWith(wrappedRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "remove-simulator-path";
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you have an image with wiremock? this is weird from their side not allowing for such a config

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: suppose you download and use a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wiremock/wiremock) of wiremock, you can't edit the code. I was expecting for an environment variable to be available to be used in such cases - to allow starting the wiremock server on a different context path.

Comment: I haven't used WireMock with a docker image, but there is information in the link you listed about registering extensions, and RequestFilters are extensions. If you're struggling to find your answers, I'd recommend asking a separate question, as this question is ~2 years old and is completely separate from the issue you're experiencing.